# How do I change the internal margins in the OutlinedTextField?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here's what I got:

[image: my OutlinedTextField]

The text in the form is shifted, as I understand it, with built-in indents. Can I somehow remove them so that the text can be seen normally?

```
OutlinedTextField(
            value = enterS,
            onValueChange = {},
            readOnly = true,
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Test")},
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(70.dp)
                .height(40.dp),
            textStyle = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center))
```

Comment: You can't. You can eat the sun as a fruit for one, but this.... nope, impossible till the end of time. FORGET IT!!!

Comment: Who are you talking to? There's only the two of us in this section